# Minimum system requirements for ubuntu 18.04

Tags: playonlinux

I want to run Ubuntu 18.04 in my machine.  Here are my system specs:

Cpu : Intel core 2 duo
Hard disk : 160 gb
RAM : 2GB DDR3

Please anyone help. Thanks in advance. ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar). But personally I can recommend Ubuntu MATE and of course buy more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to run Ubuntu Server 18.04 this should be enough for a "staging server", depends on the purpose of the installation though. If you were about to go for a Ubuntu 18.04 desktop I'd say you're not going to have a nice experience, but of course, it will boot :)